# Can anyone tell me how to use tensorflow iou function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use tensorflow mean_iou function and write a sample code as follwing; but it gives me error message

Attempting to use uninitialized value mean_iou_5/total_confusion_matrix
     [[{{node mean_iou_5/total_confusion_matrix/read}}]]

Can anyone tell me how to use mean_iou function of tensorflow?

Thanks.

```
labels1 = tf.convert_to_tensor([[3,1,2],[2,3,1]],tf.int32)
pred = tf.convert_to_tensor ([[3,1,2],[2,3,1]],tf.int32)

test,conf_mat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels = labels1, predictions = pred, num_classes = 3)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op.run()
    print('test',sess.run(test))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use tensorflow tf.metrics.mean\_iou?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643288/how-to-use-tensorflow-tf-metrics-mean-iou)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the StackOverflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326455/9820369

```
# y_pred and y_true are np.arrays of shape [1, size, channels]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ypredT = tf.constant(np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1))
    ytrueT = tf.constant(np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1))
    iou,conf_mat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(ytrueT, ypredT, num_classes=3)
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run([conf_mat])
    miou = sess.run([iou])
    print(miou)
```